# Setting up a Server on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server

My knowledge of Ubuntu is worse than basic.

I need to set up a server, so that when abroad, in Asia, I can use the server as though I were working from home. Please,

Here is my hardware etc.

Desktop PC 64 bit. Ubuntu 18.04

Odroid X-U4

Modem: Vodaphone.

Noip Hostname.

**If the reply is too lengthy can anyone suggest specific reading material, please?**

Comment: Look into remote desktop. Remmina is the default remote desktop client. You need a remote desktop server too for that to work with your server. You could also install teamviewer-servr on the server and you can use a teamviewer-client to connect.

Comment: Why 18.04?  Try to go to the latest version (20.04 LTS or 21.04) since you're setting up something  new.

Comment: "*need to set up a server*" is too vague to be answerable. The Question should discuss the actual tasks that you want the server to perform. Share files? Run games? Databases? Remote desktops? Website? Each has a different approach and details.